# Is there any connection between the Bynar and the Borg?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In the TNG episode [11001001](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11001001_(episode)), there is a humanoid species, which is integrated into a computer - the [Bynar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bynar). This sound remarkably like the Borg, who are also part-living-part-computer.

**Is there any relation between the Bynar and the Borg?**

Comment: They may be distant cousins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the Borg are not connected to the Bynar. They do share some superficial similarities, but the Borg's technological superiority is based on [nanotechnology](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nanotechnology) whereas the Bynars rely on much cruder *surgical* enhancements.

> **MONINGER:** *I believe you're looking at a form of nanotechnology. I found thousands of these in both aliens. They're not just regenerating
> the damaged tissue, they're repairing the mechanical components as
> well. As far as I can tell, this arm's as good as new.*
>
> **DRAKE:** *The Denobulans have experimented with nanotechnology, but they have nothing like this.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ent: Regeneration](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/49.htm)</sup></sub>

Dr Phlox, when investigating the Borg comments on the fact that they're not the only civilisation to use tech to improve their biological forms.

> **PHLOX:** *There's a species I once encountered in the Beta Magellan system, the Bynars. When they're born, a surgeon removes the child's
> parietal lobe and replaces it with a synaptic processor. I saw the
> procedure performed once. It was very impressive.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ent: Regeneration](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/49.htm)</sup></sub>